# Computing the expected shortfall

Tags: conditional-expectation, exponential-distribution

So here's the problem:

"In finance the level of a risk of a portfolio is often measured by the value-at-risk, i.e. , the loss that is exceeded with probability $\alpha$, or by the expected shortfall, which is the expected loss,
conditional on the loss exceeding the value at risk. If the loss distribution is exponential with mean $\mu$,
find the value-at-risk and the expected shortfall."

Here's what I've done so far.

Let $x_\alpha$ denote the value at risk . Since X (which is the random variable that represents the loss) follows an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda = \frac{1}{\mu} $, and since we know that $P(X>x_\alpha) = \alpha $, we have that: $$ 1 - e^{-x_\alpha/\mu} = 1-\alpha$$ From there we can isolate $x_\alpha$, and we will know the value risk in terms of $\mu$ and $\alpha$, which gives us: $$x_\alpha = -\mu \ \text{log}(\alpha)$$

Now the problem is to compute $E(X \ | \ X>x_\alpha )$. I tried to apply the definition of the expected value, which gives me $$\int_{x_\alpha}^{+\infty}x f(x)dx$$ where $f$ is the density of the exponential distribution. So we have: $$\frac{1}{\mu}\int_{x_\alpha}^{+\infty}x \ e^{-\frac{x}{\mu}}dx$$ which we can solve by integration by parts.

But this result does not give me a finite value, so I guess something in my reasoning is wrong.

If you could help , that would be nice.

Comment: The value of the last integral you wrote is finite, so you must be doing something wrong when taking the integral. Also, if you're taking the expectation conditional on $ X > x_{\alpha} $, then you have to work with the probability distribution of $ X $ given that $ X > x_{\alpha} $. You don't do this in the question - to do it, you have to normalize the integral by dividing by $ \int_{x_a}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx $.

Comment: Oh. So what you're saying is that $E(X \ | \ X>x_\alpha ) = \int_{x_\alpha}^{+\infty}xf(x)dx \  \cdot \ (P(X>x_\alpha))^{-1}$, where $P(X>x_\alpha) = \alpha$. Why is this the case ? I mean why do I have to normalize my initial integral to find the correct expected value  ?

Comment: Imagine you were instead computing $ \mathbb E(X | X = x_{\alpha}) $. In this case, it's obvious that this is equal to $ x_{\alpha} $, but doing the calculation as you did would give us that it is $ 0 $ (since $ X = x_{\alpha} $ with probability $ 0 $).

Comment: Makes sense...  I found $e^{-x_\alpha / \mu} \cdot (\mu + x_\alpha) \cdot \alpha^{-1}$ is that correct ?

Comment: Yes ,I think this is correct, because in the end it gives me: $\mu - \mu \ \text{log}(\alpha)$, which is the correct answer. Thank you very much for you answer.